# How to resolve method getters and their values dynamically without naming the class/type

Tags: java, spring

I am using an interface of a java bean. Most of the times the methods yielded by this interface are good enough for me.

But often enough I need to access the implementations of this interface.

The problem here is that I only have a *String* key to access a specific property of a implemented java bean.

### Problem

In my runtime I have following *String* variable with the value `successPage`.
I then have an interface `Content`. This interface does not yield a method called
`getSuccessPage()` but one of its implementations `Formular` does.

### What I would like to do

I want to use some kind of dynamic resolving of those methods. See this pseudo code:

```
Content content;
String foundValue = propertyResolver.getDynamicValue("successPage", content, String.class)
// this should ultimately call Formular.getSuccessPage() and return it's value
```

As you can see I do not have to tell the method what type the concrete implementation would have. Because I am not able to explicitly tell the runtime what type of implementation is actually used.

---

I already heard of reflection and used it by myself. But I also heard of *Spring* PropertyResolver classes. I tried to use them but was not able to understand their API and search results were not able to clear my sights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use apache commons [PropertyUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html).

```
String foundValue = PropertyUtils.getProperty(content, "successPage").toString();
```